# Convert np array to a column and append it to another dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataset.  The type of the dataset is numpy.ndarray and shape is (50,300). Then I have a df and its shape is (50,8). I would like to append dataset as one column "C" to the df.  I tried to use dataset.tolist() but then it gave me many columns of dataset. So how can I do it. Here is an example of dataset and df. Those are not real data, I just copied from internet.
Thanks for your advice!

```
Dataset: 

array([[1, 1500, 1, 2],
   [1, 1700, 3, 3],
   [1, 2000, 2, 2],
   [1, 2400, 2, 3],
   [1, 2700, 3, 3]])

Df:

      sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2    setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2    setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2    setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2    setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2    setosa

Expected output:

joined_df:

     sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species         C 
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2    setosa   [1, 1500, 1, 2]
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2    setosa   [1, 1700, 3, 3]
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2    setosa   [1, 2400, 2, 3]
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2    setosa   [1, 2700, 3, 3]
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2    setosa   [1, 3000, 3, 4]
```

If I do dataset.tolist(),

it showed like this:

```
      0    1     2    3   
0     1   1500   1    2
1     1   1700   3    3
2     1   2000   2    2
3 
4
```

Comment: So `df['C'] = dataset.tolist()` failed? What does mean `it gave me many columns of dataset` ?

Comment: @jezrel i add it to my question, one min

Comment: @jezrel sorry I only did like dataset.tolist() w/o assign it to the column, now it solved. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert array to nested list and append to column:

```
df['C'] = dataset.tolist()
```